# Add a cover page between grouped reports when selecting multiples

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Using SSRS 2008.  I have a report that is filtered by Department (dropdown parameter with ability to select multiples).  If the user selects multiple or all departments, I need to insert a cover page between each group of departments.  ANyone heard of a way to do this?

Comment: Have you investigated using a subreport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution should be to do the following:

1. Under the Row/Column Groups Panel, right-click on the group in your tablix based on Department and select Group Properties.
2. Go to the Page Break tab and check the "Between each instance of a group" option.
3. Add a new row within the Department group before the Details group.
4. Merge all the cells in the newly added row.
5. Insert a placeholder with the desired content of the cover page.

I'm still working on a way to insert a page break following the cover page, but you should be able to get this through trial and error by making the contents of that placeholder long enough (try using CHR(10) to insert numerous line returns) to force the details row to the next page.

If I find a way to insert a page break within the placeholder I'll update my answer. BTW, I tested using CHR(12) which is a form feed and would normally insert a page break but SSRS is not recognizing it as such.

Good luck!

Comment: I got it working pretty much like this.  I added a group with a header row, then specified a page break before the header row, then I put the text I wanted in the header row, which appears on the "cover page".  I then grouped the whole thing by department, so I get a cover page between departments.

Comment: How did you get the page break at the bottom of the cover page (i.e., before the data began displaying)? Anyone else trying to figure this out might benefit from further details.